# Disable webcam's Autofocus in Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I'm working in embebed system in the beagleboard. The source code is in Python, but I import libraries from OpenCV to do image processing. Actually, I'm using the webcam Logitech c910, it's a excellent camera but it has autofocus. I would like to know if I can disable the autofocus from Python or any program in Linux?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use program `v4l2-ctl` from your shell to control hardware settings on your webcam. To turn off autofocus just do:

```
v4l2-ctl -c focus_auto=0
```

You can list all possible controls with:

```
v4l2-ctl -l
```

The commands default to your first Video4Linux device, i.e. `/dev/video0`. If you got more than one webcam plugged in, use `-d` switch to select your target device.

---

**Installing v4l-utils**

Easiest way to install the utility is using your package manager, e.g. on Ubuntu or other Debian-based systems try:

```
apt-get install v4l-utils
```

or on Fedora, CentOS and other RPM-based distros use:

```
yum install v4l-utils
```

Comment: First, I had to `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`.

Comment: Just in case anyone else gets confused. The package `v4l-utils` package has a little 'L' character after the '4' and is not a '1'!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in Linux with:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
```

For some people this doesn't work in Windows (see [Disable webcam's autofocus in Windows using opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855506/disable-webcams-autofocus-in-windows-using-opencv-python)). In my system it does (ubuntu 14.04, V4L 2.0.2, opencv 3.4.3 ,logitech c922).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds is useful, I've come up with a small snippet that can be added to your `.bashrc`. It will detect which of your webcams has autofocus and disable it.
I'm using this with a Microsoft LifeCam HD-6000 that has a flawed autofocus system.

Prerequisite: `v4l-utils`

```
# Get a space-separated list of all the video devices available
webcams=$(ls -pd /dev/* | grep video | tr '\n' ' ')
for webcam in $webcams; do
  # Check if the tested video device features autofocus
  no_autofocus=$(v4l2-ctl --device=$webcam --all | grep focus)
  # If it does, disable it
  if [ -n "${no_autofocus}" ];
  then
      v4l2-ctl --device=$webcam --set-ctrl=focus_auto=0
  fi
done
```

This snippet does certain assumptions:

- You want to disable autofocus on all the video devices featuring it