# Disable webcam's autofocus in Windows using opencv-python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to disable the autofocus on my portable USB webcam (model: Trust Zyno Full HD Video Webcam) using a python and opencv. Using `cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)` as proposed in [this previous unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128097/disable-auto-focus-in-opencv-2-4), does not work for me.

I saw [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319759/disable-webcams-autofocus-in-linux) which is instead related to Linux, and others related to c++ solutions.

However, I am working on Windows 10, using Python 3.6 and opencv 3.4.0.12.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use follows:

```html
  // Turning off autofocus
  cap1.set( cv.CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 1 );
```

);